# Convert MySQL script to H2

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

I have an init script for my MySQL database but for test purposes I wan't to use a H2 database. Anyone knows how to convert the file or at least has a list of the syntax differences ? thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are [a number of database tools](http://h2database.com/html/links.html#tools) that help migrating data from one to another database, for example:

- [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org)
- [SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin](http://dbcopyplugin.sf.net/)

Comment: I had some fun creating the bash script that will convert a mysqldump file to h2 format.  https://github.com/Joebh/MysqlDumpToH2

Comment: He is not tying to migrate data, he is just looking for syntax differences between the file

Comment: @sayilaguirre why do you think so? The question is clearly about converting. Converting the table definitions, and I assume also some of the data. Those tools can do both.

Comment: @sayilaguirre if _you_ are looking for a way to look at syntax differences, then please ask a new question.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a good instruction by Matthew Casperson

[Exporting from MySQL to H2](http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.de/2013/07/exporting-from-mysql-to-h2.html)

Here is a short list of steps, to convert from mysql to h2:

> Fix up single quotes

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
convert to
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

> Fix up hex numbers
>   Fix up bits
>   Don't include ranges in keys
>   Remove character sets (remove CHARACTER SET ...)
>   Remove COLLATE settings (f.e. COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)
>   Remove indexes on BLOBS, CLOBS and TEXT fields
>   Make all index names unique
>   Use the MySQL compatibility mode (jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MySQL)

Comment: Try to include the main idea of the article in your answer. I may be  of use if the link goes down.

Comment: Its hard to do that, because Matthew discibes it very short and clearly, but i list all important steps and hope he is all right with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this java tool, It so easy to use just download and run the jar file. It has both a GUI and can also be intergrated within your code if need be. [MysqlDumpToH2](https://github.com/katwekibs/MysqlDumpToH2)

Answer (score -3):

I saw this on the iConomy FAQ (http://ico.nexua.org/Main/FAQ#toc28):

> How do I convert H2 to MySQL?
>
> Since they are both SQL based all you need to do is Export the h2 sql data into a .sql file, and import it into a MySQL database using a GUI, or PHPMyAdmin, Admininer, SQLBuddy, Etc..
>   To do this, you can either use the h2 built in console or RazorSQL h2 GUI (Multi-platform).
>   If you want the SQL output of the database, the full path to your minecraft.h2.db without the .h2.db part
>
> Use the following line inside a .sh / .bat file or console inside the /lib folder where h2.jar is located:

`java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:path/to/minecraft -user sa -password sa`

> This will output a file named backup.sql and will contain the raw SQL output of the database. You may need to edit it a bit so it matches up with MySQL.
>   :)

Comment: Isn't that the exact opposite of what was asked for?