# H2 Database - Unknown data type of MySQL script

Tags: h2, in-memory-database

I'm new in using in-memmory database.

I tried to use **H2 database** for developing project with *spring boot, spring data JPA,* but i got a problem when initialize application.

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "FK_PERSON__PERSONTYPE_IDX"; SQL statement:

Because this script was exported from MySQL. So i thinked there are some wrong syntax which H2 does not understand

For example, this is a part of script:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_person__persontype_idx` (`type`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_person__persontype` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `persontype` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='  ';
```

And i tried some solutions from these:

> [Convert MySQL script to H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610850/convert-mysql-script-to-h2)
>
> http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.de/2013/07/exporting-from-mysql-to-h2.html

Replace symbols with double quotes, single quotes,... even not use quote at all but not working.
Please show me why?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL commands not compliable by H2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676516/sql-commands-not-compliable-by-h2)

Comment: Thanks, let me check it.

Comment: Thanks win_wave for recommend, but not success. There are still many errors when i migrate from mysql script to H2 script. It's better to use mysql DB

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

Removing the "KEY" line, which in your example corrosponds to:

```
KEY `fk_person__persontype_idx` (`type`),
```

worked for me.