# SQL commands not compliable by H2

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

The following SQL commands are actually for MySQL. I am not a SQL expert and do not know much about H2. My Spring app throws an exception because the **user_roles** table can not be created. It has a problem with the `fk_username_idx`:

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_roles;

  CREATE  TABLE users (
  userid VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid));
   
  CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_role_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userid varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  role varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id),
  UNIQUE KEY uni_username_role (role,userid),
  KEY fk_username_idx (userid),
  CONSTRAINT fk_username FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (userid));
```

ERROR LOG:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unbekannter Datentyp: "FK_USERNAME_IDX"
Unknown data type: "FK_USERNAME_IDX"; SQL statement:
   CREATE TABLE user_roles (   user_role_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   userid varchar(5) NOT NULL,   role varchar(45) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id),   UNIQUE KEY uni_username_role (role,userid),   KEY fk_username_idx (userid),   CONSTRAINT fk_username FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (userid)) [50004-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:4059)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:3922)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5864)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4217)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:360)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:315)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:287)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:252)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:472)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: " It has a problem with the fk_username_idx" - post your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. are you sure your H2 runs in MySQL compatiblity mode? Check this first. By looking at the connect string. For example like this:

   ```
   final SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
   ds.setDriverClass(Driver.class);
   ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=mysql;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
   ds.setUsername("sa");
   ds.setPassword("");
   ```
2. `FOREIGN KEY fk_username_idx (userid),` is not suppported by H2. Remove `FOREIGN` here.

Then it will work