# How to redirect data from H2 database to sql server 2012 data base

Tags: sql-server, h2, wso2, wso2-business-process

How  can I  redirect data from H2 database to sql server  2012 data base  in Bpel Process Server?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610850/convert-mysql-script-to-h2

check this link, last answer

Comment: Which wso2bps version you are using ?

Comment: I am using WSO2 Business Process Server v3.5.1

Comment: @ajanthan  
I am using WSO2 Business Process Server v3.5.1